# WordPress - Rewrite rules multiple para

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

i have an URL like this:

`http://domain.de/projekte/agbz/userprofile/?page=member&memberID=Z4911331&land=deutschland&fa=zahnarzt&vorname=Henryk&nachname=Donnerstag`

I want to rewrite this URL in a structure like this:

`https://www.domain.de/deutschland/zahnarzt/dr_michael_claar_kassel_Z4901196/`

my rewrite Rule in my functions.php is like that, but its not working:

`add_rewrite_rule(
    '/agbz\/(\w*)\/\?page=(\w*)&memberID=([a-z]{1}\d*)&land=(\w*)&fa=(\w*)&vorname=(\w*)&nachname=(\w*)/',
    'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]&page=member&memberID=$matches[3]&land=$matches[4]&fa=$matches[5]&vorname=$matches[6]&nachname=$matches[7]',
    'top');`

Can anybody help me at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
www.example.com/somePage/products/?mfg=UETD342

to

www.example.com/somePage/products/UETD342/
```

you can add custom URL tag using below code:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%mfg%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

and add below code to add your own custom rewrite rule for loading your page with this parameter:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
     add_rewrite_rule('^products/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=your_page_id&mfg=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

you need to add both codes in your theme's functions.php

For a more detailed knowledge of url rewriting visit: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: thank you, why my rule dont work?
my Url ist http://example.de/userprofile/?memberID=Z4911331

`function custom_rewrite_tag() {
     add_rewrite_tag('%memberID%', '\?memberID=([a-z]{1}\d*)');
     add_rewrite_tag('%land%', '(\w*)');
 }
 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

 function custom_rewrite_rule() {
     add_rewrite_rule('\?memberID=([a-z]{1}\d*)','userprofile/?page_id=450&memberID=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);`